# PDO: Get all untested flashcards from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetchall

I am trying to get all flashcards from a specific deck (deck_id) that are pending.

A flashcard is pending when

- it hasn't been tested,
- `next_review` is not set (new card) **or**
- `next_review <= $today` (means card is due to review).

What I currently get is results from different card decks like `deck_id 1` and `deck_id 2` but I just want to retrieve pending cards from the same deck (like `deck_id = 1`).

This is what I tried:

```
//Get the untested and ready to review cards from DB
public function getCardSR($deckId)
{

    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $notSet = '0000-00-00';

$query = "SELECT tbl_repetition.repetition_id, 
                 tbl_repetition.card_id, 
                 tbl_repetition.deck_id, 
                 tbl_repetition.user_id, 
                 tbl_repetition.status, 
                 tbl_repetition.last_review, 
                 tbl_repetition.eFactor, 
                 tbl_repetition.inter, 
                 tbl_repetition.repetition, 
                 tbl_repetition.grade, 
                 tbl_cards.front, 
                 tbl_cards.back
    FROM tbl_repetition
    LEFT JOIN tbl_cards
    ON tbl_repetition.card_id = tbl_cards.card_id
    WHERE tbl_repetition.deck_id = :deckId AND 
          tbl_repetition.next_review <= :today OR 
          tbl_repetition.next_review = :notSet";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':deckId', $deckId);
    $stmt->bindParam(':today', $today);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notSet', $notSet);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $result;
}
```

This is how the results are retrieved from the `$result` array:

```
$repetition_id = $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]  ["repetition_id"];
$eFactor =       $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["eFactor"];
$card_id =       $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["card_id"];
$deck_id =       $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["deck_id"];
$user_id =       $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["user_id"];
$status =        $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["status"];
$last_review =   $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["last_review"];
$inter =         $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["inter"];
$repetition =    $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["repetition"];
$grade =         $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["grade"];
$front =         $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["front"];
$back =          $decks->getCardSR($c)[$repetitionCard]["back"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) in your `WHERE` clause.

Now, you are doing this :

```
WHERE tbl_repetition.deck_id = :deckId AND 
      tbl_repetition.next_review <= :today OR 
      tbl_repetition.next_review = :notSet
```

Let's call first expression 1, second 2 and third 3.

Which means it will be evaluated like this :

1. `AND` will be evaluated first, so it will do `(1 AND 2)`
2. `OR` will be evaluated second, so you will result in `(1 AND 2) OR 3`

This means you will retrieve all cards from one deck that need review today AND all cards from all decks that review is not set...

To solve this you must place parenthese to make the `OR` to be evaluated first :

```
WHERE tbl_repetition.deck_id = :deckId AND 
      (tbl_repetition.next_review <= :today OR 
      tbl_repetition.next_review = :notSet)
```

That way you will have what you want

Comment: Thank you so much SuperPeanut. This worked and solved my issues.

Comment: @Kamesan mark the post as the answer if it worked, so next with same problem will be able to see how to solve it.